# c# webclient not timing out

Tags: c#, timeout, webclient

Im trying to download files using extended WebClient with set timeout and I have a problem with the timeout (or what I think should cause timeout).

When I start the download with WebClient and receive some data, then disconnect wifi - my program hangs on the download without throwing any exception. How can I fix this?
EDIT: It actually throws exception but way later than it should (5 minutes vs 1 second which i set) - that is what Im trying to fix.

If you find anything else wrong with my code, please let me know too. Thank you for help

This is my extended class

```
class WebClientWithTimeout : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        w.Timeout = 1000;
        return w;
    }
}
```

This is the download

```
using (WebClientWithTimeout wct = new WebClientWithTimeout())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    try
    {
        wct.DownloadFile("https://example.com", file);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Download: {0} failed with exception:{1} {2}", file, Environment.NewLine, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to download asynchronously to keep UI active

Comment: The program doesnt have UI so I dont really mind it being synchronous. What bothers me is that if something happens on the network and the file cant be downloaded, then the download doesnt timeout.

Comment: okay got it, see my answer maybe you can implement async call and decide when to cancel the request. Maybe use a time and check if there's a download progress if not cancel download

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can avoid UI blocking by this. Coming the WiFi when device connects to WiFi the download resumes.

```
//declare globally
 DateTime lastDownloaded = DateTime.Now;
 Timer t = new Timer();
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
```

//declarewherever you initiate download my case button click

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += Wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += Wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
        lastDownloaded = DateTime.Now;
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Tick += T_Tick;
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/archive/master.zip"), @"C:\Users\chkri\AppData\Local\Temp\master.zip");
    }

    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - lastDownloaded).TotalMilliseconds > 1000)
        {
            wc.CancelAsync();
        }
    }

    private void Wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            lblProgress.Text = e.Error.Message;
        }
    }

    private void Wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lastDownloaded = DateTime.Now;
        lblProgress.Text = e.BytesReceived + "/" + e.TotalBytesToReceive;
    }
```